# preg_match dose not work correctly in php

Tags: php, regex

all,

I am using preg_match to filter some data, and it is strange that, it dose not work correctly. I am new to regex, and I used a php live regex website to check my regex, which works correctly. So I have no idea what is wrong here. 
I would like to have preg_match to find something like "a\_b" in the $string:

```
$string="aaa\_bbb:ccc"
if(preg_match("/[a-zA-Z]\\_[a-zA-Z]/", $string)){
    $snew = str_replace('\_', "_", $string);
}
```

But it is strange that even I have a $string like in this example above, the result of preg_match is 0. But when I change it to

```
preg_match("/\\_[a-zA-Z]/", $string)
```

It works fine and return 1. But of course that is not what I want. Any idea?
Thanks very much~

Comment: Why do preg_match for this? Just perform `str_replace` - if string is present, it will be replaced - and will be not if not present, obviously

Comment: @Alma Do Mundo, the $string I give is an example, I have more data like "aaa/\_bbb" and "aaa,\_bbb", which I do not want to replace.

Comment: @zhihong - that doesn't make any difference; the `str_replace` will still only replace the one with a backslash. Also, if you really do need a regex here, have you considered using `preg_replace` to do both operations in one line?

Comment: @Sniffer, I am generating sql file for database, but for some reason, string like this type "aaa\_bbb:ccc", the "\" dose not escaped data correctly, and I got the "Unknown command '\_" error. And I tried after replace "\_" to "_", then sql file can be imported correctly

Comment: @Spudley, but the preg_match can help to filter the lines first, and if other cased as "aaa/_bbb" and "aaa,_bbb" will not be processed. I think this can be more efficient. And thanks, yes, use preg_replace is better

Comment: @zhihong - No it will not be more efficient. The `preg_match()` is doing more work than the `str_replace()`, so you're actually making it *less* efficient by using a `preg_match()` to save it from having to do a `str_replace()`. In any case, that kind of 'efficiency' saving is not worth thinking about -- if your program is slow, use a profiler to find out where the *real* bottlenecks are, and fix those; don't waste time trying to fix theoretical efficiencies that don't actually make any real difference.

Comment: @zhihong: re your note to Sniffer... please note; if the problem is with the original escaping, you should fix the original escaping rather than trying to correct it afterwards like this. Maybe you should ask a question about how to do that instead.

Comment: @Spudley, thanks for your suggestion. Will consider that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't really need the `preg_match` at all, from what I can see.

However the problem you're having with it is to do with escaping.

You have this: `"/[a-zA-Z]\\_[a-zA-Z]/"`

You've correctly identified that the backslash needs to be escaped, however, you've missed a subtle issue:

Regular expressions in PHP are strings. This means that you need to escape it as a string *as well as* a regular expression. In effect, this means that to correctly escape a backslash so it is matched as an actual backslash character in your pattern, you actually need to have *four* backslashes.

```
"/[a-zA-Z]\\\\_[a-zA-Z]/"
```

It's not pretty, but that's how it is.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

use:

```
if(preg_match("/[a-zA-Z]\\\\_[a-zA-Z]/", $string))
```

instead

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `preg_match` altogether, instead just do a replace using this regex:

```
/([a-zA-Z])\\\\_([a-zA-Z])/
```

and then replace with `$1_$2`, like this:

```
$result = preg_replace("/([a-zA-Z])\\\\_([a-zA-Z])/", "$1_$2$, $string);
```